# Set bg image size in netsuite advanced pdf template

Tags: netsuite

I have set a background image.Now i have to set size to small but it is not changing its size

```
 <style>
body{
    background-image:url("https://system.eu2.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=3081&amp;c=4667350&amp;h=6b67f18b9fc482ab3827");
    background-size:100px 100px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a PDF then there are quite a few css properties that are not implemented. It looks like size is one of these.

One potential workaround though would be to use a background macro instead of an image.

https://bfo.com/products/report/docs/tags/atts/background-macro.html

You should be able to have an img element in the macro and set the size directly.

Comment: What if I want to set it for an image on first page only ie. css selector #page1? I need to scale an image to cover the background, maintain aspect ratio, and have it be on page 1 only.

Comment: @jakeehoffmann You'd call the macro out in a stylesheet rather than as an element attribute `#page1{background-macro:watermark;},`